# Organize Shared folders in Sharefile

Tags: sharefile

I have several folders in my Sharefile account that were either shared with me by others or vice versa.

I want to organize them in a directory structure of my choosing (which would be somewhat equivalent to setting "mount points" for the folders).

**Is this possible?**